# How to make firebase database rule work with admin.database().ref (cloud function)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with Cloud Function for Firebase. When I use `admin.database().ref` then all the rules that applied to the database were ignored. With admin, I can do anything. To be clear:

I have a real-time database with have a set of rules such as; name must be string and length >= 50,...

It works when using the SDK, all the invalid data will be denied. But when I move to use firebase cloud function (to reduce work in client side by providing a set of https endpoints) it didn't work anymore.

So, I wonder if there is any way to make it work? I was thinking about:

1. find something replace for `admin.database()` (took a look on
   `event.data.ref` already but this does not work in my case - HTTP request)
2. verify data in cloud function (not nice)

Could you give me some hints/clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected default behavior of the Firebase Admin SDKs: the code accesses the database with administrative privileges.

If you want to limit what the code can do, you can initialize it to run as a specific UID. From the documentation on [Authenticate with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges):

> To get more fine-grained control over the resources a Firebase app instance can access, use a unique identifier in your Security Rules to represent your service.
>
> ...
>
> Then, on your server, when you initialize the Firebase app, use the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` option to override the auth object used by your database rules. In this custom auth object, set the uid field to the identifier you used to represent your service in your Security Rules.
>
> ```
> // Initialize the app with a custom auth variable, limiting the server's access
> admin.initializeApp({
>   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
>   databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
>   databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
>     uid: "my-service-worker"
>   }
> });
> ```

Please see the linked documentation for the complete example.

Comment: Frank, can you please update your answer to handle `functions.config().firebase` for Cloud Functions?